# Understanding load path in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working with a library which has a lot of ruby files generated by protocol Buffers for ruby.

The example of a require path is as follows for a file in `/path/to/source_folder/lib_name/level_1/level_2/level_3`

```
require 'lib_name/level_1/level_2/level_3/file_name_1' 
require 'lib_name/level_1/level_2/level_3/file_name_2'
```

All the necessary files and folders are contained inside a `source_folder` with some location. Had this example been in C++ then we can run this using

```
g++ file_name.cpp -I "/path/to/source_folder"
```

I cannot really change every require to `require_relative` and make changes to the main code as it will be too cumbersome. I am trying to find a simple way to run my files.

Comment: So, have you tried adding this folder to the load path? `$LOAD_PATH.unshift "/path/to/source_folder"` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked for me.   
I am actually very surprised to post a question for such a trivial problem but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solution.

```
% tree .
.
├── lib
│   └── dir1
│       └── dir2
│           ├── a.rb
│           └── b.rb
└── main.rb

% cat a.rb
def method_a
  puts :execute_a
end

% cat b.rb
def method_b
  puts :execute_b
end
```

No.1 add load path all sub directories

```
def add_load_path_recursive(dir)
  Dir.glob(dir + "/**/*/").each do |dir|
    $LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path(dir)
  end
end

add_load_path_recursive "./lib"

require 'a'
require 'b'

method_a
method_b
```

No.2 require all 'rb' files (recursive)

```
def require_recursive(dir)
  Dir.glob(dir + "/**/*.rb").each do |dir|
    require File.expand_path(dir)
  end
end

require_recursive "./lib"

method_a
method_b
```